# Why when apply the kernel mask to get Gaussian images, the output is only white images with no content?

Tags: python, image, image-processing

This is my code and I am trying to make the image bluer but there are no images are shown only white image, I don't know what is the problem:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
from collections import Counter
from skimage.color import rgb2lab, deltaE_cie76
import os

%matplotlib inline
image = cv2.imread('C://Users/user/Desktop/g.jpg')
print("The type of this input is {}".format(type(image)))
print("Shape: {}".format(image.shape))
plt.imshow(image)
image= np.array(image, dtype=np.uint8)
image= cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
k = np.array(np.ones((11, 11), np.float64))/121
k = np.array(([2, 2, 2], [2, 3, 2], [2, 2, 2]), 
np.float64)
k = k / 19
print(k)
output = cv2.filter2D(image, -1,  k)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
cv2.imshow('original', image)
plt.title('Original Image')
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
cv2.imshow('filter img', output)
plt.title('Filtered Image')
plt.show()
cv2.imshow('original', image)
```

This is what I am getting:

[image: output]

Comment: Why are you mixing up `cv2.imshow()` and `plt.show()`? Just use one. Why are you converting the Numpy array you get from `imread()` into a Numpy array? Why are you assigning to `k` three times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark Setchell mentioned in a comment you are mixing up cv2.imshow() and plt.show().
While testing it my kernel died. I fixed the last lines of your

```
output = cv2.filter2D(image, -1,  k)
plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(image), plt.title('Original')
plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(output), plt.title('Filtered Image')
```

The other lines can remain as they are. (Edit: except of the part where you assign k three times, as Mark Setchell also mentioned, you should maybe fix this part too)